# Explanation of how binary operator '&' Works in Java Card

Tags: java, javacard

How do i explain this code to a class of Java Card Beginners in a way they will understand it perfectly:

```
private void getBalance(APDU apdu) {
    byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

    // inform system that the applet has finished
    // processing the command and the system should
    // now prepare to construct a response APDU
    // which contains data field
    short le = apdu.setOutgoing();

    if (le < 2) {
        ISOException.throwIt((byte) 0x6A86);
    }

    // informs the CAD the actual number of bytes
    // returned
    apdu.setOutgoingLength((byte) 2);

    // move the balance data into the APDU buffer
    // starting at the offset 0
    buffer[0] = (byte) (balance >> 8);

    buffer[1] = (byte) (balance & 0xFF);//How do i explain what happens here



    // send the 2-byte balance at the offset
    // 0 in the apdu buffer
    apdu.sendBytes((short) 0, (short) 2);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you even need the `& 0xFF` here.

Comment: @user2357112: Indeed not.

Comment: `(byte) 0x6A86` - what the heck? That looks a lot like a bug. Half the magic number is just thrown away.

Comment: Tell them to google bitwise operation on the internet? I mean, the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) does a pretty good job of explaining it if you can't.

Comment: it is javacard and because of the targeted platform, strings, int, long and some datatype are not supported, only short and byte data type is supported, so that is why there is a lot of casting to byte in the code

Comment: Still that `ISOException.throwIt((byte) 0x6A86);` sould certainly be `ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x6A86);`

Comment: You don't need to pass APDU anymore, there is a static method for that. Explain that Le should really be Ne in Java Card. Fix the ISO exception issue from Michael, and explain that `throwIt()` has control flow issues (it is not seen as an exit point). Explain that the status word is not correct. Explain that it is better to use an `offset` instead of constant values, call `apdu.setOutgoingLength()` later and use `Util.setShort()` instead of doing those shifts etc. In other words, fix your code before you start explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

Explain binary representation of integers.
Explain the >> shift operator.
Explain hexidecimal notation, and what 0xFF becomes.
Explain bitwise and/or operators.
Put it all together to show how the combination of >>8 and &0xFF breaks a 16-bit value into high and low bytes.
Ask if there are any questions.